# Creating raster cell squares around SpatialPoints (until a certain value range of the raster cells is achieved)

Tags: raster, r, buffer

I have a DEM raster and a list of SpatialPointsDataFrames (data available here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT).

EDIT: (with regard to @Spacedman's comment)

I want to calculate the smallest N for each data point such that the raster values in an NxN square around each SpatialPoint's square have an elevation range (max-min) >= 15metres. It should look something like the picture below, where the brown raster cell is the one with a SpatialPoint inside and the blue line represents the extent of the NxN square.

[image]

I've looked at the help for the raster:focal function as proposed by @JeffreyEvans, but I don't see any possibilities to input my SPDF as source for the focal points.

Comment: So if you have N points you want N polygons? Even for cells with multiple points? What about adjacent cells with points in? If not, then you are really only creating a number of squares centred on the cell centres with a various offsets and you can do this without buffering at all...

Comment: The squares can overlap, that should not be the problem. 
In the end, I want to calculate the difference in elevation between the cells of each square and automatically enlarge every square until a certain value (for example 15 meters) is reached. 
The solution provided by @Sam seems to fit, I will try that.

Comment: You should probably reword your question, because the answer doesn't give you a polygon vector at all - it returns a data frame of the cell indexes of the neighbours. Try and ask about what you want to achieve rather than how you think you are going to do it.

Comment: I think that you are simply looking for the raster::focal function. You would then just pull the resulting focal raster values for your points.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, this sounds useful. Maybe you could post this as a real answer and help me further: 
I've looked through the help for raster::focal - how do I specify the focal points? I don't see any input possibility for a SpatialPointsDataFrame...

Comment: This is your problem - "I want to calculate the difference in elevation between the DEM cells inside my "buffer" and enlarge the "buffer" until a certain threshold is passed (15 m elevation difference). ".  Can we concentrate on *that*? You want to find the smallest N for each data point such that the raster  values in the NxN square around that point's square has an elevation range (max-min) > 15metres?

Comment: @Spacedman, I want to do exactly that! Thanks for rewording my problem!

Comment: And just for clarity - and only because a square seems an odd area to be interested in - you really want a square and not a circle of some radius?

Comment: This square method was proposed by Frey et al. (http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/tc-8-2313-2014). I know it seems odd, but I just need the adjacent cells - and the adjacent cells to them and so on, until the elevation range is >= 15m.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `raster::adjacent` function. This function can extract raster cells surrounding a given cell. You don't need to bother buffering the points.

I'm not sure what level of visualisation you want from your final product, but this produces a data frame with cell numbers, data and xy coordinates;

```
require(raster)

# make a dummy raster
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=10,ymn=0,ymx=10,res=1)
r[] <- sample(1:5,ncell(r), replace=T)

# make some dummy points
points <- data.frame(x=round(runif(10, 0.0, 10.0),1), y=round(runif(10, 0.0, 10.0),1))

# create a SpatialPointsDataFrame
coords <- cbind(points$x, points$y)
pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, points)

# Add an attribute to SPDF that is the cell number of the raster, per point
pts$cellno <- extract(r,pts,cellnumbers=T)[,"cells"]

# use the 'adjacent' function to extract queen's case raster cells, per point
# this requires the cell numbers we extracted above
li <- lapply(pts$cellno, function(x) adjacent(r,x, directions = 8, include=T))

# collapse to one data frame
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, li)

# add a column that is the values of the cells, per point
df$val <- extract(r,df[,2])

# if you want, merge in the XY data
df.all <- merge(df, pts@data, by.x = "from", by.y = "cellno")
```

Comment: So, where I appreciate your ingenuity here, this kind of over complicates the solution. You can accomplish exactly the same thing by simply running a focal function and then taking the "at cell" values of the points.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans yes you're right, and i also found quicker solutions myself but i thought this a little more transparent for OP. Which is perhaps patronizing. But yes, quicker ways and less complicated also.